# Working with a text file in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have built a simple client using then node.js framework which allows the user to post a thread onto a virtual whiteboard.

However, each time a new user joins a session, they cannot view any ideas posted by other users in the session prior to their arrival.

1) I decided the best way to alleviate this problem is by loading the older threads from a text file whenever a new user joins the session. But how do I go about doing this?

2) I wanted to know how I can go about writing data to this text file, so that whenever someone posts a thread, it is written to the text file.

3) I wanted to know if it is possible to also delete values from this text file? I'm working on a feature that lets admin delete threads from the virtual whiteboard. The values are currently deleted client side, but I would also like them to be deleted in the text file.

Here is my code so far:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.htm');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('send message', function(data) {
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

**main**

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('#chat').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    var socket = io.connect();
    var $messageForm = $('#sendmessage');
    var $messageTitle = $('#title');
    var $messageBox = $('#message');
    var $chat = $('#chat');

    $messageForm.click(function (e) {
        if ($.trim($("#title").val()).length === 0) {
            alert('You must provide valid input');
            $messageTitle.val('');
            $messageBox.val('');
            return false;
        }
        if ($.trim($("#message").val()).length === 0) {
            alert('You must provide valid input');
            $messageTitle.val('');
            $messageBox.val('');
            return false;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send message', '<span class="idea"><b>' + $messageTitle.val() + '</b>' + '&nbsp;-&nbsp;' + $messageBox.val() + '&nbsp;' + '[' + '<a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>' + ']</span>');
            $messageTitle.val('');
            $messageBox.val('');
        }
    });

    socket.on('new message', function (data) {
        $chat.prepend(data)
    });
});
```

Comment: You will most likely not want to use a text file and use some sort of database. MongoDB is pretty quick and easy.

Comment: Text files? For extremely small apps, maybe. But you'll be writing a lot of logic to parse the text files. A waste of time IMHO. Use JSON or if you need a little more sophistication and if you don't want any external dependencies, an in-process database is the way to go. Checkout https://github.com/rvagg/node-levelup